# running Sublime Text build with latex instead of pdflatex from LaTeXTools plugin

Tags: build, makefile, latex, sublimetext2

In the build  file  supplied with the LatexTools plugin for Sublime Text,  I modified the statement

```
"cmd": ["latexmk", "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'", "-f", "-pdf"]
```

by replacing the second instance of pdflatex with latex.
My question is, how do  I specify whether I want  to use "dvipdfm" or "dvi2ps + ps2pdf".

If someone could provide a sample build file for this purpose, that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error, I finally have the following build file working correctly. This allows me to choose between pdflatex and latex, and also choose between dvipdfm and the  alternative of "dvi2ps + ps2pdf"

```
    // Compilation settings
    // ====================
    //
// The actual magic happens in the make_pdf command
// I stick to the format of standard ST2 sublime-build files
// with minor variations.
// NOTE: the viewer is NOT configured from here! 
// As of 5/24/11, it cannot be changed, but I will introduce a setting later

{
    // General settings; DO NOT MODIFY!!!
    "target": "make_pdf",
    "selector": "text.tex.latex",

    //-----------------------
    // Linux-specific settings
    // ----------------------
    // If  linux/os variable is used, then command palette does not show variant names

        // Linux texification settings
        // -------------------------
        // Personalize this, IF you know what you are doing!
        // e.g. change 'pdflatex...' to 'xelatex...'
        // Refer to the documentation for latexmk
        //
        // Note: do NOT include $file or similar!!!
        // Only configure the compilation parameters you need, MINUS the
        // actual file to be compiled
        // 
        // By default, latexmk is told to use pdflatex, with synctex on for
        // backward/forward search, forcing compilation (e.g. even if no bib file is found)
        // and producing pdf rather than dvi output



        "cmd": ["latexmk",
                "-e","\\$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S'", "-e", "\\$latex = 'latex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
                "-f", "-pdfdvi"],


        "variants":
        [

        { "cmd": ["latexmk",
                "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
                "-f", "-pdf"],
          "name": "Run"
        },


        { "cmd": ["latexmk",
                "-e", "\\$latex = 'latex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
                "-f", "-pdfps"],
          "name": "LaTeX_PS_PDF"
        },

        {"cmd": ["latexmk", "-e",  "\\$clean_ext = 'aux fls fdb_latexmk dvi ps synctex.gz'", "-c"],
         "name" : "Clean "
        }

        ]       
}
```

Comment: Just a link to the related question for anyone interested:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114576/run-shell-script-bash-commands-in-sublime-text-latex-build-without-any-file-argu/16133159#16133159