# run shell script/bash commands in Sublime Text latex build without any file arguments

Tags: json, bash, build, latex, sublimetext2

I have a sublime text build system for running latex.  I am using  a shell script (with no arguments) to delete the various extensions that are generated by latex.
The problem is that sublime-text thinks filename.tex is the argument to the script.

So I tried the following script:

```
    {

// General settings
"target": "make_pdf",
"selector": "text.tex.latex",


"cmd": ["latexmk", "-e","\\$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S'", "-e", "\\$latex = 'latex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'","-f", "-pdfdvi"],

"variants":
[

    { "cmd":["my_script.sh"],
      "name": "clean"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I used ls in place of the script to illustrate. When I run the build-file, it tries to run

```
my_script.sh filename.tex
```

instead of just my_script.sh. What can I do  to run just that from the build file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been there and done that . . . there and back again . . . and visited again and again . . .

The solution is to use a custom plugin (not necessarily relying upon a `.sublime-build`, but that is possible too) so that you can refer to the *.tex file that is open.  I have some solutions you are probably unaware of, one of which is my own, and one where I modify the popular plugin LaTexTools.

latexmk cleans with a big -C (everything) or a little -c (some things that are pre-defined, and additional things that can be user-defined) -- so there is no need to use a separate custom cleaner script.

https://github.com/lawlist/LaTexTools-Unofficial-Modification

https://github.com/lawlist/ST2-plugin-latexmk-save-build-clean

FYI:  I recommend putting latex (or something like that) in your subject line of the question -- I almost missed your question . . . and just happened to see the short summary and realized I knew something about this issue.

---

SAMPLE -- for MultiTaskBuild plugin located here:  https://github.com/bizoo/MultiTaskBuild

```
{
    "cmd": {

        "latexmk -pvc . . .": {
            "cmd": ["latexmk", "-r", "/Users/HOME/.latexmkrc", "$file"]
        },

        "latexmk -pv . . .": {
            "cmd": ["latexmk",
        "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -enable-write18 %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
         "-recorder-", "-pvc-", "-f", "-pdf", "-pv", "$file"]
        },

        "latexmk -c": {
            "cmd": ["latexmk", "-c", "$file"]           
        },

        "latexmk -C": {
            "cmd": ["latexmk", "-C", "$file"]
        }
    },
"path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)",
    "selector": "text.tex.latex",
    "default_task": "latexmk -pv . . .",
    "target": "multi_task_exec"
}
```

Comment: I added "latex" in the subject line of the question now following your suggestion. The two solutions mentioned above dont solve my problem. I already have a "clean" command set up using latexmk, but the issue is that in a multifile document using the \include command, there are .aux extensions created for every file, and not just for the root document. If you have a method that would clean them up too, that would help.  Also, I would like to know how  I could  execute a simple command like  "cmd":["/usr/bin/ls -la"] in the above build file;

Comment: If you are using make_pdf (aka makePDF.py) of LaTexTools, then the place to call your script is from within that makePDF.py.  Within my modification of that file, I have chosen relevant points of beginning and ending the build process.  The python "call" subprocess permits executing things like the script you want to use -- a sample of using the subprocess.call is within the second link I provided.  If you are not using makePDF.py of LaTexTools, then I would need more information to better assist you.

Comment: I'll add a variant build based upon a variant plugin, which is a little different than what you are doing, but kind of similar . . . The plugin is MultiTaskBuild.

Comment: You can also execute a script with a keyboard shortcut:  `{ "keys": [""], "command": "exec", "args": { "cmd": ["/path/to/script.sh", "-options", "-additional_options" ] } },`

Comment: If you are able to turn LaTeX.sublime-build of LaTexTools into a variant build, please post your solution -- I'd be interested in an alternative to the MultiTaskBuild relating to LaTexTools.

Comment: You might also be interested in a solution by bjmorgan:  https://gist.github.com/bjmorgan/4349538  That option uses the CMD for a script, but involves another build file -- too many for my personal tastes.

Comment: I will explore your idea involving the keyboard shortcut further; I quite like it, but I confess I am rather out of my depth with your multitask build. I do not quite understand how it works. My build script with variants is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034941/running-sublime-text-build-with-latex-instead-of-pdflatex-from-latextools-plugin    As I said before, I am able to get by with this, I can choose any of the 3 modes  to generate pdf output, and also clean the tex root extensions.

Comment: I suggested the MultiTaskBuild example because it looks similar to what you are trying to accomplish by modifying the LaTeX.sublime-build of LaTexTools.  The `target` of what you are trying to modify is makePDF.py, so naturally any variant of that LaTeX.sublime-build file will be targeting that script, which is probably why your own script is not doing what you would like it to do.  Here is the link to the MultiTaskBuild plugin that may be more suited to your needs:  https://github.com/bizoo/MultiTaskBuild.